# Filter an array in javascript cross browser

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a little problem. i searched but did not get help to solve it. I have an array for example `var oldArr=['one','two','3'];` and i want to make a new array from this but only with **string** values and for that i am currently `using Array.filter` method and it is working but some one said that it is not supported in all browsers so my question is how can i filter my array with a cross browser solution.

This is my current code

```
var oldArr=['one','two','3'];
newArr=oldArr.filter(function(a){
return !a.match(/\d/);
});
alert(newArr);
```

Thank you in advance for your effort.

Comment: Those all look like strings. What you mean is only get strings that don't parse as numbers?

Comment: Have a look at the [shim proposed by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility)

Comment: @AbuRasel - Didn't [do research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) = downvote

Comment: Sorry for my mistake , i want to get numbers only.

Comment: @Derek following your logic, almost every question desires DV :)

Comment: @VisioN - [Let me Google that for you.](http://bit.ly/LjTIXP) Second item.

Comment: @Derek Oh, thank you. Seems like I don't know where to search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you want this

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;
        if (typeof fun != "function") {
            throw new TypeError();
        }

        var res = [];
        var thisp = arguments[1]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in this) {
                var val = this[i];
                if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this)) {
                    res.push(val);
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    };
}

var oldArr = ['one','two','3'];
    newArr=oldArr.filter(function(a){
    return !a.match(/\d/);
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Reference: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/UkPXd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldArr = ['one', 'two', '3'];
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(oldArr[i])) {
        newArr.push(oldArr[i]);
    }
}
```

isNaN evaluates if something is convertable to a number. It is also cross-browser compatible.

If you wanted to get everything that *IS* a number, you'd just add a bang to the conditional:

```
if (!isNaN(oldArr[i])) {
```